# Finding the derivative of sinus and cosinus. Trigonometric identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can we see that $$\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)=2\sin\left(\frac h2\right)\cos\left(x+\frac h2\right)$$

How can we see that $$\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)=-2\sin\left(\frac h2\right)\sin\left(x+\frac h2\right)$$

Do these identities have a name?

Comment: Use the formula for $\sin(a+b)$ and $\sin（a-b)$ with $a=x+h/2$ and $b=h/2$.

Comment: also these may help also http://www.analyzemath.com/Trigonometry_2/Pro_sum_formulas.html

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a name: Looks like an application of the reverse of the [Prosthaphaeresis identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis), or [sum-to-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) identities.

$$
\sin a − \sin b = 2 \cos\frac{a + b}{2} \sin\frac{a − b}{2} \\
\cos a − \cos b = −2 \sin\frac{a + b}{2} \sin\frac{a − b}{2}
$$
using $a = x + h$ and $b = x$.

Another link [here](http://planetmath.org/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas).

I usually use the complex definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to proof, but you probably want an elementary one.

Note there are four identities in total.

$$
\sin a + \sin b = 2 \sin\frac{a + b}{2} \cos\frac{a − b}{2} \\
\cos a + \cos b = 2 \cos\frac{a + b}{2} \cos\frac{a − b}{2}
$$

which would yield
$$
\sin(x+h) + \sin(x) = 
2 \sin\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{h}{2}\right) \\
\cos(x+h) + \cos(x) = 
2 \cos\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

For any $a,b$, we have the well known "addition theorems"
$$ \sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$$
and $$ \sin(a-b) = \sin a \cos b - \sin b \cos a $$
Subtracting these two equations, we get 
$$ \sin(a+b) - \sin(a-b) = 2\sin b \cos a $$

For the cosine, we have
$$ \cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b $$
and $$ \cos(a-b) = \cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b $$
Subtraction again 
$$ \cos(a+b) - \cos(a-b) =  -2\sin a\sin b$$
Now let $b = \frac h2$, $a = x+\frac h2$.